# Glyph collision in newtxtext

Tags: kerning, newtx

I would like to avoid programmatically what, to my eyes, is a collision between the italic glyphs for "g" followed by "f" with the `newtxtext` package. Inserting a kern value between the two of them in the document is a no-go because it would make the contents of the source file typeface-dependent.

Please feel free to correct me if you think that I am wrong in the occurrence of the collision. It is slight, but it is there, and I do not think it qualifies as a ligature.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Follows an MWE (as trivial as it gets):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}
\emph{meaningful}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I sent mail to the maintainer of `newtx` about the issue. He's usually very responsive.

Comment: Well, that may be the *ultimate* solution. Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that preserves LaTeX's ability to insert a line break (and a hyphenation symbol) between `meaning` and `ful` should LaTeX deem it to be necessary.

The solution inserts a kern of width `0.035em`. (If that doesn't produce quite enough glyph separation for you taste, feel free to increase the kern to `0.04em`.)

The code includes a test whether the `newtxtext` package is loaded; if that's *not* the case, the macro `\meaningful` does not insert a kern, i.e., it just outputs the string "meaningful".

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\newcommand\gfkern{\discretionary{g-}{f}{g\kern0.035emf}}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{newtxtext}{%
     \newcommand{\meaningful}{meanin\gfkern ul}}{%
     \newcommand{\meaningful}{meaningful}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\emph{meaningful} -- unadjusted

\emph{\meaningful} -- adjusted

\emph{meanin\discretionary{g-}{f}{g\kern0.035emf}ul} -- brute force

\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum*, meant to address some broader issues related to the apparent "entanglement" of, or "collision" between, the italic-shaped `g` and `f` glyphs.

Let's start by investigating how much extra kerning is needed to avoid the glyph entanglement for four separate fonts: Times Roman -- the text font used by the `newtxtext` package is based on a clone of Times Roman -- as well as Times New Roman, EB Garamond, and Latin Modern Roman. In the following table, the font sizes have been adjusted to that x-sizes of all four fonts are the same.

[image]

As is readily apparent, the italic versions of Times New Roman and especially EB Garamond require far more kerning (`0.08em` and `0.13em`, respectively) than Times Roman does (`0.035em`) in order to keep the `g` and `f` glyphs from touching/colliding/getting entangled. On the other hand, Latin Modern needs no kerning adjustment at all. Observe, moreover, that introducing `0.08em` and especially `0.13em` of extra kern manages to create a visual void between "meaning" and "ful" -- not good!

My simple advice would be to learn to appreciate the font designers' work when it comes to the side-by-side placement of the `g` and `f` glyphs, and hence not to bother with any kerning adjustments. *De facto*, the entanglement of the `g` and `f` glyphs has created a composite or ligated glyph. Now, ligatures *should be* suppressed if their presence risks misleading the reader. (For sure, that's the basis of the work of the `selnolig` package.) In the case of the word "meaningful", however, there's got to be zero chance that any reader might be confused, slowed down, or otherwise inconvenienced by the presence of a gf "ligature" in the italic version of the word "meaningful". Hence, no (typographic) purpose is served by suppressing this de-facto ligature.

Last but not least, here's the code for the preceding table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,booktabs}
\newcommand\gfkern[1]{\discretionary{g-}{f}{g\kern#1emf}}
\newcommand{\ingful}[1][0.035]{in\gfkern{#1}ul}

\newlength\mylena
\newlength\mylenb
\setmainfont{Times}[ItalicFont=Times Italic]
\settowidth\mylena{Times New Roman}
\settowidth\mylenb{\textit{meaningful}\ \ \ }
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\mylena}p{\mylenb}p{\mylenb}l@{}}
Font & Unadjusted & Adjusted & Required kern \\
\midrule
Times Roman &\textit{meaningful} & \textit{mean\ingful} &  0.035em \\
\end{tabular}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[ItalicFont=Times New Roman Italic,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\mylena}p{\mylenb}p{\mylenb}l@{}}
Times New Roman &\textit{meaningful} & \textit{mean\ingful[0.08]} &  0.08em \\
\end{tabular}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[Numbers=Lining,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\mylena}p{\mylenb}p{\mylenb}l@{}}
EB Garamond & \textit{meaningful} & \textit{mean\ingful[0.13]} & 0.13em\\
\end{tabular}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\mylena}p{\mylenb}p{\mylenb}l@{}}
Latin Modern Roman & \textit{meaningful} & \textit{mean\ingful[0]} & 0.00em\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your approach is the one I took in my document before asking the question. It certainly solves the issue, but I would rather act somehow where it is suitable on the `newtxttext` package so as to avoid having to tweak a "regular" word in the source file.

Comment: @Marcos - Just out of curiosity: Do you have any other cases of g-f glyph collisions in your source file?

Comment: @Mico My most sincere and heartfelt compliments for your ability.

Comment: @Marcos - I've added a test to the code, so that the macro `\meaningful` inserts a kern only if the `newtxtext` package is loaded. Thus, it should be safe to replace all instances of the word `meaningful` that occur in text-italic mode with `\meaningful`.

Comment: @Mico: It is the only occurrence. I do appreciate your effort, which I will validate as the answer if there is no sensible way to act directly on the package contents. The latter would be my first choice.

Comment: @Mico: You've made a strong point (if not more than just a single one). Not only I appreciate your effort and attention but I have a bad feeling about not checking your contribution as the answer.  My ultimate reason, and this concerns also your point, is that I think that this "overlap" is not a ligature; i.e., it is not by design as such a pair, but rather by accident in the design of the glyphs on a separate basis. I have paid close scrutiny to the pair "gf" and such is my perception. I may be wrong, though. And it is more notorious with the garamond-like typeface, that I otherwise love.

Comment: @Marcos If you compare the ‘gy’ and ‘gj’ ligatures with ‘gf,’ it becomes evident that the kerning of ‘gf’ in EB Garamond is intentional.